# rolling window in python of positive values in a list

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, mean

What is a pythonic way to calculate the mean of a list ,but only considering the positive values?

So if I have the values 
[1,2,3,4,5,-1,4,2,3] and I want to calculate the rolling mean of three values it is basically calculating the average rolling average of [1,2,3,4,5,'nan',4,2,3]. 
And that becomes
[nan,2,3,4,4.5,4.5,3,nan] where the first and the last nan are due to the missing elements. 
The 2 = mean ([1,2,3])
the 3 = mean ([2,3,4])
but the 4.5 = mean ([4,5,nan])=mean ([4,5])
and so on. So it is important that when there are negative values they are excluded, but the division is between the number of positive values.

I tried:

```
def RollingPositiveAverage(listA,nElements):
     listB=[element for element in listA if element>0]
     return pd.rolling_mean(listB,3)
```

but the list B has elements missing. I tried to substitute those elements with nan but then the mean becomes nan itself.

Is there any nice and elegant way to solve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using Pandas:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def RollingPositiveAverage(listA, window=3):
     s = pd.Series(listA)
     s[s < 0] = np.nan
     result = s.rolling(window, center=True, min_periods=1).mean()
     result.iloc[:window // 2] = np.nan
     result.iloc[-(window // 2):] = np.nan
     return result  # or result.values or list(result) if you prefer array or list

print(RollingPositiveAverage([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, -1, 4, 2, 3]))
```

Output:

```
0    NaN
1    2.0
2    3.0
3    4.0
4    4.5
5    4.5
6    3.0
7    3.0
8    NaN
dtype: float64
```

---

Plain Python version:

```
import math

def RollingPositiveAverage(listA, window=3):
    result = [math.nan] * (window // 2)
    for win in zip(*(listA[i:] for i in range(window))):
        win = tuple(v for v in win if v >= 0)
        result.append(float(sum(win)) / min(len(win), 1))
    result.extend([math.nan] * (window // 2))
    return result

print(RollingPositiveAverage([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, -1, 4, 2, 3]))
```

Output:

```
[nan, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 4.5, 4.5, 3.0, 3.0, nan]
```

Comment: thanks. This looks like the most promising answer. What does "s[s < 0] = np.nan" do?

Comment: @PietroSperoni That's to replace negative values in `s` with `NaN`, so the rolling mean will skip those in the calculation. Passing `min_periods=1` later allows to compute the mean on windows with missing values (that includes the beginning and end, that's why I added the following lines to manually replace them with `NaN`, as in your intended output).

Comment: Would this work if the window is much bigger and there are many more NAN inside. Say I am calculating it on a 360 window (out of a list of 1800 values) with 800 nan's scattered around the list?

Comment: @PietroSperoni You can give it a try, but it should work, as long as there is at least one valid positive value in the window. Obviously, if you have a long sequence of negative values and/or `NaN`s you would see `NaN`s in the output too, since there are no valid elements to average (in the Pandas version, the Python version, as it is now, would produce zeros for those windows)...

Comment: That's fine. The problem is that when I tried np.mean([3,float("NaN"),5]) it gave me nan. So I don't understand why .mean() is ignoring the nan while in pandas is correctly ignoring those value. I need to test it before accepting it, sorry

Comment: @PietroSperoni Do you also have NaNs apart from negative numbers in the input list?

Comment: @PietroSperoni Pandas is allowed to "skip" that `NaN` because the `min_periods` parameter allows it to compute on windows with missing values, but in any case, yes, definitely test it before accepting.

Comment: and it works! And no "in theory" there should not be nan :-). But in practice. So basically you use the pandas mean, and then take away the first nan. I don't even need to do that actually.

Answer (score 2):

Get rolling summations and get the count of valid elements participating with rolling summations of the mask of positive elements and simple divide them for the average values. For the rolling summations, we could use [`np.convolve`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.convolve.html).

Hence, the implementation -

```
def rolling_mean(a, W=3):
    a = np.asarray(a) # convert to array
    k = np.ones(W) # kernel for convolution

    # Mask of positive numbers and get clipped array
    m = a>=0
    a_clipped = np.where(m,a,0)

    # Get rolling windowed summations and divide by the rolling valid counts
    return np.convolve(a_clipped,k,'same')/np.convolve(m,k,'same')
```

Extending to the specific case of `NaN-padding` at the boundaries -

```
def rolling_mean_pad(a, W=3):
    hW = (W-1)//2 # half window size for padding
    a = np.asarray(a) # convert to array
    k = np.ones(W) # kernel for convolution

    # Mask of positive numbers and get clipped array
    m = a>=0
    a_clipped = np.where(m,a,0)

    # Get rolling windowed summations and divide by the rolling valid counts
    out = np.convolve(a_clipped,k,'same')/np.convolve(m,k,'same')
    out[:hW] = np.nan
    out[-hW:] = np.nan
    return out
```

Sample run -

```
In [54]: a
Out[54]: array([ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5, -1,  4,  2,  3])

In [55]: rolling_mean_pad(a, W=3)
Out[55]: array([ nan,  2. ,  3. ,  4. ,  4.5,  4.5,  3. ,  3. ,  nan])
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This answer went way over my head, sorry.